# Rotate an svg image to 90 deg

Tags: css

I have an svg image

[image]

i want to rotate it so that it looks like this:

[image]

tried adding css:

```
  svg {
     transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
```

but its not working.

Comment: Image is mirrored horizontally, title says rotate 90 degrees, code says rotate 60 degrees. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

The image in your question is not rotated, it's flipped (mirrored) horizontally. You can achieve this by scaling by a factor of -1 on the X axis:

```
svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1)
}
```

Comment: How will this work(rotate) , as till now I only think `scale` is for `size` . Can you tell something

Comment: Look at your image. It's not rotated, it's flipped horizontally. Scaling by a factor of -1 has the same effect as flipping an image.